# Посев моделей с парой случайных, но связанных в разных моделях полей laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Есть сущности `template`, они распределены по сущностям `category`. У обеих сущностей есть поле `type`, которое случайно генерируется в фабриках. Но должно совпадать при случайном распределении шаблонов по категориям

Следующий код создает 10 категорий, сохраняет их **id**-шники в **коллекцию** и они  **рандомно** назначаются шаблонам. Но вот беда. Их типы должны совпадать. Код ниже не учитывает этой особенности. И типы шаблонов и категорий не совпадают, что логично.

```
    Category::factory()->count(10)->create();
    $category_ids = Category::all()->pluck('id');

    Template::factory()->count(50)->create([
        'category_id' => function () use ($category_ids) {
            return $category_ids->random();
        }
        //Здесь должно быть еще поле 'type'
    ]);
```

Попробовал сделать такой вариант, но не сработало

```
    Category::factory()->count(10)->create();
    $category_ids = Category::all()->pluck('id');
    $random_id = 1;
    
    Template::factory()->count(50)->create([
        'category_id' => function () use ($category_ids, &$random_id) {
            $random_id = $category_ids->random();
            return $random_id;
        },
        'type' => function () use (&$random_id) {
            return Category::find($random_id)->type;
        },
    ]);
```

Если проверить по `$ramdom_id` (совпадет id совпадет и тип), то вначале выполняется код для элемента `'type'` со значением начальной инициализации

```
type 1
cat 6
type 6
cat 4
type 4
cat 10
type 10
cat 8
```

Но если переметить фунцию `random()` к элементу `'type'`

```
Category::factory()->count(10)->create();
    $category_ids = Category::all()->pluck('id');
    $random_id = 1;

    Template::factory()->count(50)->create([
        'type' => function () use ($category_ids, &$random_id) {
            $random_id = $category_ids->random();
            return Category::find($random_id)->type;
        },
        'category_id' => function () use (&$random_id) {
            return $random_id;
        },
    ]);
```

То все работает

```
type 9
cat 9
type 2
cat 2
type 12
cat 12
type 1
cat 1
```

У меня два вопроса.

1. Этот массив обрабатывается в обратном алфавитном порядке или дело в `'category_id'`?
2. Это вообще нормальный способ решения или ерудна? Если ерунда, то тогда как по нормальному сделать?

Comment: а зачем Вам тип в шаблоне? Вы по сути соединяете две таблицы по двум ключам. Далее происходит дубль данных, в данном случае `type`. В результате, допустим у меня тип 1 был и там и там, потом я захотел сменить  его на другую цифру. Это мне надо будет залезть в две таблицы и везде поменять? а если у меня уже 3 таблицы будет? У вас есть уже в категории тип и он совпадает с тем что в шаблоне. Если надо будет найти по типу шаблон, то будет как-то так: `Template::whereHas('category', function($q) use ($type){ $q->where('type', $type) })->first()` и всё.

Comment: @Dmitrii Sedov менятся оно так вряд ли будет, но наверно Вы правы. Меня тоже сначало смутило дублирование данных. Почему-то думал, что так проще считать будет. Типа у меня всего два: доход и расход. В принципе можно пересчитывать и категориями. Спасибо. Сейчас так и сделаю. Сколько раз убеждаюсь, что когда у меня дело доходит до вопроса на SO, то значит я делаю какую-то дичь)